# RegEx pattern needed to return the same found pattern under two different group names

Tags: c#, regex

Currently I'm using some kind of tree that has a regular expression on each level to parse some arbitrary text file into a tree. Till now everything works quite fine and the regex result is given down to the child node to do further parsing of the text. To get a link between the node and a child node the node itself has also a name, which is used within a regex as the group name. So after parsing some text I'll get a regex containing some named groups and the node itself also contains of child nodes with the same names, which leads to a recursive structure to do some arbitrary parsing.

Now i'm running into trouble, cause to make the processing of this tree in the next step a little bit easier i need the very same information within the text file under different nodes within my tree. Due to the fact, that this is maybe a little bit hard to understand, here is a unit test that shows what i'd like to achieve:

```
string input = "Some identifier=Just a value like 123";
// ToDo: Change the pattern, that the new group 'anotherName' will contain the same text as 'key'.
string pattern = "^(?'key'.*?)=(?'value'.*)$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(input);

var key = match.Groups["key"];
var value = match.Groups["value"];
var sameAsKeyButWithOtherGroupName = match.Groups["anotherName"];

Assert.That(key, Is.EqualTo(sameAsKeyButWithOtherGroupName));
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Cylians answer and writing my own comment to him i did a little more research about the back references and my test will succeed with this slightly little changed regular expression:

```
string input = "Some identifier=Just a value like 123";
string pattern = @"^(?'key'.*?)(?'anotherName'\k<key>)=(?'value'.*)$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(input);

var key = match.Groups["key"];
var value = match.Groups["value"];
var sameAsKeyButWithOtherGroupName = match.Groups["anotherName"];

Assert.That(key, Is.EqualTo(sameAsKeyButWithOtherGroupName));
```

So conclusion is quite simple: If you need the same group under another name, simple declare this group and use the content of another group as pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

To call a back reference in a .NET pattern, you have to specify `\k<name_of_group>` syntax. May try this one:

```
bool foundMatch = false;
try {
    foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(?<authorName>(?'key'.*?)=\k<key>)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
^(?<authorName>(?'key'.*?)=\k'key')$

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “authorName” «(?<authorName>(?'key'.*?)=\k'key')»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “key” «(?'key'.*?)»
      Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “=” literally «=»
   Match the same text as most recently matched by the named group “key” «\k'key'»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
-->
```

Comment: Yes, i already read something about back references within regular expression, but i didn't know how to use them in my concrete example. As far as i understand it will allow you to use the content of a group within the same regex. But i need the content under another group name. So it sounds like it should possible somehow, but i couldn't grasp it till now. If you understood it, could you tell me the concrete expression to make my above test working?